# Links label are overlapped between each other

Tags: javascript, gojs

I have created two square shapes and connect them with links by their ports. But when I create more than two links, their link labels starting overlap (You can see this in screenshot below).
Is GoJS has some options to correctly align or separate labels?

[image]

Comment: please edit your post and add your example code in your question.

Comment: @novonimo, I'm just asking about possibility in goJS. Can goJS do this stuff or not? If you know something about it, please share this info.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that you are using multiple ports.  Assuming the ports are positioned along a side of a node, there isn't much choice for where links could connect with the node.

Instead, the default behavior for a node with a single port might be what you are looking for:

```
  function init() {
    var $ = go.GraphObject.make;

    myDiagram =
      $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv");

    myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
      $(go.Node, "Auto",
        new go.Binding("location"),
        $(go.Shape,
          { fill: "white", portId: "" },
          new go.Binding("fill", "color")),
        $(go.TextBlock,
          { margin: 8 },
          new go.Binding("text"))
      );

    myDiagram.linkTemplate =
      $(go.Link,
        //{ curve: go.Link.Bezier },
        $(go.Shape),
        $(go.Shape, { toArrow: "OpenTriangle" }),
        $(go.TextBlock, { background: "white" },
          new go.Binding("text"))
      );

    myDiagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel(
    [
      { key: 1, text: "Alpha", color: "lightblue", location: new go.Point(0, 0) },
      { key: 2, text: "Beta", color: "orange", location: new go.Point(200, 50) },
      { key: 3, text: "Gamma", color: "lightgreen", location: new go.Point(50, 200) }
    ],
    [
      { from: 1, to: 2, text: "12" },
      { from: 1, to: 2, text: "a long label" },
      { from: 2, to: 1, text: "345" },
      { from: 1, to: 3, text: "13" },
      { from: 1, to: 3, text: "short" },
      { from: 3, to: 1, text: "34567890" }
    ]);
  }
```

produces:

[image: multiple links with variable breadth link labels]

Or if you specify Bezier curve links:

[image: multiple Bezier links]

Move the nodes around and you can see how the distance between the links changes based on the breadth of the link labels, since the labels are not circular.

Comment: yep, we have figured out that when we use more than one port, our link have not curves. but when we connect them to one port, all is just work fine.